# Get data from the server using React Js

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-select

I am using `react-select` library and I want to get data from a test API into the  select. This is how my code looks:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

const WithPromises = () => {
  const filterData = (inputValue) => {
    const req = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=6")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        return res.map(({ title }) => {
          return {
            label: title,
            value: title
          };
        });
      });
    console.log(req, "promise from server");
    return req;
  };

  const promiseOptions = (inputValue) => {
    filterData(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      isClearable={true}
      isSearchable={true}
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={promiseOptions}
    />
  );
};

export default WithPromises;
```

I tried to get data in the opened dropdown of the select but i did not manage.

 How to populate with data the dropdown? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-zsj6i?file=/example.js:0-787

Comment: you should retun `filterData(inputValue)` in  `promiseOptions` shouldn't you?

Comment: @AmirhosseinEbrahimi, could you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302083/how-to-make-an-infinite-scrolling-using-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

I think you are updating your options before getting any response from server. You should use async-await block to get the data from server. If you update your promiseOptions block with following may help you. Please have a look to the following code.

```
const promiseOptions = async (inputValue) => {
    return await filterData(inputValue);
};
```

I hope this will help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to log response from api. You are mapping on res, we got multiple objects in response and the data which we need is in data object. So first check your res in console

Comment: what do you mean? Could you show a sanbox please? Thanks

Comment: const promiseOptions = inputValue =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(filterData(inputValue));
    }, 1000);
  });
replace your function with this.Its getting a promise , you need to resolve it to get data.

Comment: could you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302083/how-to-make-an-infinite-scrolling-using-reactjs