# How to make an infinite scrolling using ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to make an infinite scrolling. The idea is next, when user scroll at the bottom of the scroll area, the http request should occur and to add data to the previous, that exists before. In this way the user if will scroll back to the top will be able to see all options.
For this i created:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

const WithPromises = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]); //here should be added all data
  const filterData = (inputValue) => {
    const req = fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=15&_page=${page}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, "data");
        return res.map(({ title }) => {
          return {
            label: title,
            value: title
          };
        });
      });
    return req;
  };

  const promiseOptions = (inputValue) => {
    return filterData(inputValue);
  };

  const scroll = (e) => {
    setPage(page + 1); //when scroll is at the bottom
  };
  console.log(page);
  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      onMenuScrollToBottom={scroll}
      isClearable={true}
      isSearchable={true}
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={promiseOptions}
    />
  );
};

export default WithPromises;
```

How you can see i increment the page every time the user is at the bottom of the scroll area.
`setPage(page + 1)`. The value is added in the request. 
Question: How to achieve what i decsribed above? When i will scroll down the new values should be added in the whole list and to be saved there and if i will scroll again at the boottm the the page should change and again new data should be added in the whole list. 
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-zsj6i?file=/example.js:0-1070

Comment: could you explain your issue more, I guess the sandbox you posted did what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

[react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) have an [InfiniteLoader](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/InfiniteLoader) HOC which you can use for the implementation of your infinite scrolling menu, let me give you an pseudocode:

```
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  const [rowCount, setRowCount] = React.useState(0);

  const rowRenderer = ({ key, index, style }) => (
    <div key={key} style={style}>
      {items[index]}
    </div>
  );

  const isRowLoaded = ({ index }) => {
    return !!items[index];
  };

  const loadMore = ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) => {
    fetch(`https://blahblahblah.com/getData?from=${startIndex}&to=${stopIndex}`)
      .then((res) => res.json)
      .then((response) => {
        setRowCount(response.data.count); //number of results!
        return response.data.items.map(({ title }) => ({
          label: title,
          value: title,
        }));
      })
      .then((formattedData) => setItems((prev) => [...prev, formattedData])); //add new datas to the previous list
  };
  return (
    <InfiniteLoader
      isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded}
      loadMoreRows={loadMore}
      rowCount={rowCount}>
      {({ onRowsRendered }) => (
        <List
          onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
          rowCount={rowCount}
          rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
        />
      )}
    </InfiniteLoader>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but could you help please to find a solution for my example? It will be very helpful.

Comment: The react-select does not have any pagination option if you wanna use react-select to make an infinite scroller, u can use 'react-select-async-paginate' which is a wrapper for 'react-select' that help you.

Comment: but maybe is possible to use spread operator to concat the values like: `page > 1 && setAllData([...allData, ...fetchedData]);
        return [...fetchedData, allData];`  , ?

Comment: how do you think? I want to concat each next values that i will get scrolling down at the bottom.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the spread operator, but the problem is to know when the user will reach the end of the list ...